# Angular 10+ | ng-select what is the default value of appendTo

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-ngselect

I'm using the same component on top of a modal and on a regular page.

```html
<ng-select
[items]="obs$ | async"
[appendTo]="body"
>
</ng-select>
```

This works for the regular page, but for a modal, the select values go behind the modal.
What will be the value of appendTo if I don't provide it with any value.

```html
<ng-select
[items]="obs$ | async"
>
</ng-select>
```

this works for modal but not for the regular page. The select menu gets clipped

```html
<ng-select
[items]="obs$ | async"
[appendTo]="null" -> this doesn't work (i.e) the select options are behind the modal
>
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default value for `appendTo` is the `ng-select` component itself. It will render the select panel as a child of that component. By passing a selector for `appendTo`, you are telling the component that it should find that element in the DOM and attach it as a child there.

This is useful because sometimes `ng-select` may be used inside of a parent element with a fixed height and scroll hidden, and this would cause some of the options to be unviewable. By passing a value to the selector of a parent element that doesn't have those CSS properties, ie `[appendTo]=".some-scrollable-content"`, the options in the panel can be reached.

If you are having trouble using this in a modal, you could try using the modal panel for the `appendTo`. [Here](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/demo/app/examples/append-to-example/append-to-example.component.html) is further details on `appendTo` property provided by the `ng-select` team.

As for `[appendTo]="null"`, I think that is equivalent to not defining it at all. Here is the source code where the property is used, and the `if` statement would be passed by for both `null` or `undefined`.

```
private _onSelectionChanged() {
  if (this.isOpen && this.multiple && this.appendTo) {
    // Make sure items are rendered.
    this._cd.detectChanges();
    this.dropdownPanel.adjustPosition();
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/src/ng-select/lib/ng-select.component.ts) is a link to the code.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source code of ng-select, the default is to place the dropdown directly inside the  element. For a modal, this can cause problem by clipping or showing scroll bar.

You should append it to the body and change the `z-index` of `.ng-dropdown-panel` in css to be greater than the modal.